# How to order by calculated column in knexjs

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I'm trying to add a calculated/computed/virtual column to a query by doing the following:

```js
knex.select(knex.raw('DATEDIFF("2018-04-15", STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, "%d/%m/%Y")) / 365.25 as age'))
.from('user')
.orderBy('age', 'desc');
```

However, I end up with the following error:

```
BadRequest: select count(`user`.`id`) as `total` from `user` order by `id` desc, `age` desc - Unknown column 'age' in 'order clause'
```

I think it may have something with how I'm structuring my query, but it doesn't seem to recognize the calculated column as one that can be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`orderByRaw`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-orderByRaw) and repeat your expression not just the alias

```
knex.select(knex.raw('DATEDIFF("2018-04-15", STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, "%d/%m/%Y")) / 365.25 as age'))
.from('user')
.orderByRaw('DATEDIFF("2018-04-15", STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, "%d/%m/%Y")) / 365.25', 'desc');
```

I guess knex generates another query to get total count of records excluding the `select()`part.

Answer (score 0):

Your bad request error and knex query doesn't match. The error is coming from some other query (count query built from that knex query).

You can see the generated query here: https://runkit.com/embed/4au5bdj29j8j

```
select DATEDIFF("2018-04-15", STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, "%d/%m/%Y")) / 365.25 as age from `user` order by `age` desc
```

Knex does not generatate any count queries automatically.

If you are using plain knex you should drop the `order by` part from the count query with `.clearOrder` method http://knexjs.org/#Builder-clearOrder

If that count query is created by some ORM you are using, then solution depends on that ORM how to avoid this problem.